# How long is it safe to use iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, security

I have an iPhone 4. I would like to know: since iOS 8 is not going to work on the iPhone 4, when should I be worried about the security of my device, since iOS 7 will eventually cease to be supported by most apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to know is that once an OS is no longer supported, it doesn't immediately become full of security problems. It's also not beyond Apple to give updates to non-current (for want of a better description) versions of iOS for major security problems. Therefore, it's not possible at this stage to say when iOS 7 will be insecure.

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand, you should always be alert to the security of your device -- and you clearly are so.

On the other, it is most likely that any targeted future attacks will be made on iOS 8, rather than on older operating systems, assuming the user adoption rate measures near that of iOS 7. I would feel comfortable using iOS 7 until/unless Apple announces a major security update to iOS 8 which is being made because of discovery of a major security flaw. You may, however, feel more comfortable simply removing all your banking or other sensitive information from the phone; I would not worry about passwords for most sites as those are being stolen en masse from databases rather than via targeted user attacks -- unless you're a young, attractive, famous woman.

One of the best ways to ensure the security of your personal information is to always use a VPN when you use public WiFi.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Thankfully (?) I am not a young, attractive, famous woman, so I don't need to worry about being targeted, per se.